# PHP - Filter by value and omit in loop

Tags: php

I will do my best to explain this and keep it short as well. I am parsing a JSON file. I have created variables based on keys from the JSON and loop through it. I already have one array_filter that filters values in the loop I want to allow. What I am not sure of is how to go a step further and do another check and disallow by the value of a different key/variable.

In my JSON I have this key/object...

```
"geocode": {
                    "UGC": [
                        "TXZ179",
                    ],
```

Now the varible I have created for this to get this value is like so...

```
$geocode = $currFeature['properties']['geocode']['UGC'][0];
```

Now if you notice the value it is

> TXZ179

I only need to the first two letters from that value so I have stripped it down to show only the first two letters like so...

```
$state = substr($geocode, 0, -4);
```

This leaves me with the value of TX from above.

I explained that to explain this. I want to take that $state variable and filter out and omit values in my loop that = TX from that variable.

Before I loop through my parsed JSON I filter it by values that I want to SHOW like so...

```
//Lets filter the response to get only the values we want
$alerts = array(
    'Tornado Warning',
    'Severe Thunderstorm Warning',
    'Hurricane Warning',
    'Tropical Storm Warning',
    'Flash Flood Warning',
    'Flood Warning',
);

// filter features, remove those which are not of any of the desired event types
    $alertFeatures = array_filter($features, function(array $feature) use ($alerts) {
    $eventType = $feature['properties']['event'];

    return in_array($eventType, $alerts);
});

// flip alerts, mapping names of alerts to index in array (we'll use it to order)
$order = array_flip($alerts);

// sort elements by order of event type as desired
usort($alertFeatures, function (array $a, array $b) use ($order) {
    $eventTypeA = $a['properties']['event'];
    $eventTypeB = $b['properties']['event'];

    return $order[$eventTypeA] - $order[$eventTypeB];
});
```

This question has to do more with filter OUT by a certain value while already having an existing array_filter to ALLOW by certain values and how they can both co-exist.

So my problem is due to the lack of knowledge. I am not sure what function to use or how to disallow by the value of TX in the $state variable. From my knowledge array_filter is for to filter out values you want to keep. So how can I remove values with TX before I loop throw it and it passes the first array_filter.

Comment: You have not tried to perform this task.  You are asking us to write your code for you.  Please try first and tell us where you are stuck. Use `substr($geocode,0,2)` to get the first two.  Your question shows no reseach or attempt to self-solve and may be downvoted.  Please update your question.

Comment: Filtering multidim arrays on deep values has been asked before.

Comment: While your question provides the needle value (`$state`), it does not provide a haystack value (`$features`).   I hope that when you are back in a week, you will include this in your questions so that they all contain a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If you edit your other recent questions regarding this project, I will be happy to upvote them all for being complete questions.  I am not attacking you, I am supporting you and SO.  (I will not be editing your question while you are away -- that would be counterproductive to what I hope can be accomplished cooperatively.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can augment your existing filter function to also exclude features based on their geo information.

```
// this is the TX You don't want
$ignoreState = 'TX';

// filter features, remove those which are not of any of the desired event types
// and also remove those from $ignoreState
$alertFeatures = array_filter($features, function (array $feature) use ($alerts, $ignoreState) {
    $eventType = $feature['properties']['event'];
    $isValidEvent = in_array($eventType, $alerts);

    $geocode = $feature['properties']['geocode']['UGC'][0];
    $isValidState = substr($geocode, 0, 2) != $ignoreState;

    return $isValidState && $isValidEvent;
});
```

The filter function is just a function that is supposed to return `true` if you want the array item (`$feature`) to be in the resulting array, or `false` if you want the array item to be excluded from the resulting array.

In your case, you want the array item to the in the resulting array if its event is one of the whitelisted events (`$alerts`) and if the state code (`$state`) is not `TX`.

Comment: What doe the "$isValidState" do? I am already doing substr() with the $state variable to trim down the $geocode variable to return the first two characters of the geocode value. Does $isValidState do the same thing or is it performing something different.

Comment: PHP substr creates new string, and then compares, the code with strncmp was faster and used less memory. This might be a bit more readable, but why hinder performance and use more stack? :)

Comment: I have $state = substr($geocode, 0, -4); in my loop which does the same thing. Should I just add the != $ignoreState to that in my loop?

Comment: Marcin, best not to dive down the micro-optimisation rabbit hole in this discussion.  Texan78, next time you're "already doing" something, please show it in the question so we can help you properly.

Comment: @Texan78 In the question you state that you're using `substr()` *somewhere*, which is great. However, that little tidbit appears nowhere in your example code, not even a `// I'd like to use $state here` comment.  Then in the comments here you say, "I have $state... in my loop", again that is great, but not what you showed us.  Anyway, this is all by-the-by.  Do you have any further questions still?

Comment: See... if You'd just keep the strncmp it would work either way, regardless if the data was stripped or not, and would not ignite this discussion. I know too well premature optimization is the root of all evil. But I know even better to save RAM, whenever I can :)